# Is there a way to simplify typing Swift trailing closure?

Tags: xcode, swift

Trailing closure make code more readable, but the coding process is not enjoyable at all. For example, when I want to type this kind of method (shown below) that only takes one closure parameter. There is no Code hint for choosing trailing closure:

[image]

I have to delete content inside`()`, and type the complete closure like that :

[image]

Is there a way to make this easier?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Type `ENTER` twice, once to complete the method name, a second time to automatically format the closure.

When I begin to type the function name:

[image]

After hitting `ENTER` once:

[image]

Then, after hitting `ENTER` a second time:

[image]

To sum up: type the first letters of the function, wait for auto-suggest, then hit ENTER then ENTER again.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly with say `.toolbar(content: () -> View)` it only replaces the `() -> View` with `{
code
}` and doesn't make a trailing closure. It does however work in other cases. Maybe a bug in XCode? ‍♂️

Comment: @GazB Xcode 13's formatting system is broken indeed, it should work.

Answer (score -2):

If the closure takes parameters, you just do:

```
actionButton.snp_makeConstraints { make in 
    // Stuff
}
```

Multiple params:

```
actionButton.snp_makeConstraints { make, extraParam in
    // Stuff
}
```

No params:

```
actionButton.snp_makeConstraints {
    // Stuff
}
```

For future reference: http://goshdarnclosuresyntax.com

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. They asked how to get to this result easier using code hints. You've explained what a trailing closure is.