# Swift - how to implement completion handler with trailing closure?

Tags: swift, closures

Suppose I have function that does some stuff

```
func doSomethingAwesome(completion:(success:Bool) -> Bool) {

//some stuff

}
```

How can I transform it to trailing closure ? How can I transform control from body of function to completion block ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What you're showing is a function implementation that takes a closure parameter. "Trailing closure syntax" is a shorthand notation that applies to the invocation of the function. This function can be invoked using trailing closure syntax. Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Reminder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33020097/2227743

Answer (score 1):

It is already trailing closure. You can call completion in body:

```
func doSomethingAwesome(completion:(success:Bool) -> Bool) {

    //some stuff
    let result = completion(success: true)
}
```

And thats how you can use trailing closure syntax calling this func:

```
doSomethingAwesome {
        success in
        return success
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call that function (which already has a trailing closure) by doing:

```
doSomethingAwesome{ finished in

    if finished{
          return true
    }
return false
}
```

Your completion handler is of type `Bool`. So `Bool` is used as I showed here.

Comment: Your code will not compile: you passed `Bool -> Void` closure.

Comment: Edited. Thanks! :)

Comment: will not compile again =) you used unresolved identifiers, use `true`/`false` instead

Comment: Done! Thanks! Again!