# func writeImageToFile(path: String, completeBlock: (success: Bool) -> Void){ }

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

i am trying to upload images using DKimagepickercontroller and this is a way to upload it to a url but i am confuse what i am suppose to put into the `completeBlock: (success: Bool) - Void`

```
func writeImageToFile(path: String, completeBlock: (success: Bool) -> Void){

}
```

this is the code that i wrote in xcode
    `let apath = "http://localhost/swift/upload.php"
    writeImageToFile(apath,completeBlock: (success: false) -> Void)`
but i got this error

```
expected expression in the list of expressions and this error expexted ',' separator
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it like that `writeImageToFile(path) { success in print(success) }`

Answer (score 0):

This block is supposed to be used as a trailing closure, don't leave it in the signature.

It looks like this in Xcode: [stackoverflow.com/a/33020097/2227743](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33020097/2227743)

The closure argument is used once the task is done, in your case it will indicate if the file has been written or not.

You can for example test `success` in the closure:

```
writeImageToFile(somePath) { (success) in
    if success {
        // the file has been written
    } else {
        // the file hasn't been written
    }
}
```